# How can I preprocess a tf.data.Dataset using a provided preprocess_input function that expects a tf.Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Having a bit of a clueless moment, I'm looking to apply transfer learning to a problem using [ResNet50](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/ResNet50) pre-trained on ImageNet.

I've got the transfer learning process all ready to go, but need my data set in the right form which [`tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/preprocess_input) handily does. Except it works on a `numpy.array` or `tf.Tensor` and I'm using [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) to load the data which gives me a `tf.data.Dataset`.

Is there a simple way to use the provided `preprocess_input` function to preprocess my data in this form?

Alternatively, the function specifies:

> The images are converted from RGB to BGR, then each color channel is zero-centered with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling.

So any other way to achieve this in the data pipeline or as part of the model would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `map` function of `tf.data.Dataset` to apply the `preprocess_input` function to every batch of images:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

def display(ds):
  images, _ = next(iter(ds.take(1)))
  image = images[0].numpy()
  image /= 255.0
  plt.imshow(image)

def preprocess(images, labels):
  return tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(images), labels

train_ds = train_ds.map(preprocess)

display(train_ds)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you take `labels` as a pass-through argument here? The docs all seem to say that `map_func` should be 1 input and 1 output.

Comment: It is more explicit IMO. You could of course just pass the images though or you could pass one argument called `data` and then  write `images, labels = data` or just run `train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (preprocess_input(x), y))`. Whatever floats your boat. More information can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map